# Good Java programming video tutorials anyone?

Tags: java

Anyone know how good thenewboston (http://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston#grid/user/FE2CE09D83EE3E28) video series on YouTube is?  I know he has a lot of subscribers and millions of views but how good are his skills from the prospective of other experienced Java programmers?  I would hate to learn bad approaches.

Answer (score 3):

In future you should post these sorts of questions on the [Programmers Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site.

If you want to learn best practices your best bet is to learn from *multiple sources*. That way you see the content from *multiple perspectives* and that is the best way to gain your own perspective on the subject. You sound pretty keen on videos although to be honest I wouldn't recommend them. You can learn much more from written articles, tutorials and books like [Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) and the official [Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) etc. with examples and exercises. You cannot learn programming without doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but if you want good programming videos, check out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMDCCdjyW8  It's basically classes being taught to you for free.